# In Ruby on Rails, how do I query for items that have no associated elements in a has_many :through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Contact model, and a User model, and a join table and each is HABTM more or less.

How can I query for the Contacts that have no users assigned to them?  Driving me nuts.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you should do a raw SQL query something along the lines of....

```
select c.*
from   contacts c left join contacts_users cu on c.id = cu.contact_id
where  cu.contact_id is null
```

I don't know of any pretty ORM-specific way to do it. Obviously you'll want to tailor the query to use the actual fields from your table.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this thread is looking for the same thing right?

[Want to find records with no associated records in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319400/want-to-find-records-with-no-associated-records-in-rails-3)

If I understand you correctly, then I think it could be something like:

```
Contact.includes(:jointablenames).where( :jointablenames => {:contact_id => nil } )
```