# Want to find records with no associated records in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel, meta-where

Consider a simple association...

```
class Person
   has_many :friends
end

class Friend
   belongs_to :person
end
```

What is the cleanest way to get all persons that have NO friends in ARel and/or meta_where?

And then what about a has_many :through version

```
class Person
   has_many :contacts
   has_many :friends, :through => :contacts, :uniq => true
end

class Friend
   has_many :contacts
   has_many :people, :through => :contacts, :uniq => true
end

class Contact
   belongs_to :friend
   belongs_to :person
end
```

I really don't want to use counter_cache - and I from what I've read it doesn't work with has_many :through

I don't want to pull all the person.friends records and loop through them in Ruby - I want to have a query/scope that I can use with the meta_search gem

I don't mind the performance cost of the queries

And the farther away from actual SQL the better...

Answer (score 125, accepted):

This is still pretty close to SQL, but it should get everyone with no friends in the first case:

```
Person.where('id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(person_id) FROM friends)')
```

Comment: Just imagine you have 10000000 records in friends table. What about performance in that case?

Comment: @goodniceweb Depending on your duplicate frequency, you can probably drop the `DISTINCT`. Otherwise, I think you'd want to normalize out the data and index in that case. I might do that by creating a `friend_ids` hstore or serialized column. Then you could say `Person.where(friend_ids: nil)`

Comment: If you're going to use sql, it's probably better to use `not exists (select person_id from friends where person_id = person.id)` (Or perhaps `people.id` or `persons.id`, depending on what your table is.) Not sure what the fastest is in a particular situation, but in the past this has worked well for me when I was not trying to use ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 583):

### Update 4 - Rails 6.1

Thanks to [Tim Park](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5370668/tim-park) for pointing out that in the upcoming 6.1 you can do this:

```rb
Person.where.missing(:contacts)
```

Thanks to [the post](https://blog.saeloun.com/2020/01/21/rails-6-1-adds-query-method-missing-to-find-orphan-records) he linked to too.

### Update 3 - Rails 5

Thanks to @Anson for the excellent Rails 5 solution (give him some +1s for his answer below), you can use `left_outer_joins` to avoid loading the association:

```
Person.left_outer_joins(:contacts).where(contacts: { id: nil })
```

I've included it here so people will find it, but he deserves the +1s for this.  Great addition!

### Update 2

Someone asked about the inverse, friends with no people.  As I commented below, this actually made me realize that the last field (above: the `:person_id`) doesn't actually have to be related to the model you're returning, it just has to be a field in the join table.  They're all going to be `nil` so it can be any of them.  This leads to a simpler solution to the above:

```rb
Person.includes(:contacts).where(contacts: { id: nil })
```

And then switching this to return the friends with no people becomes even simpler, you change only the class at the front:

```rb
Friend.includes(:contacts).where(contacts: { id: nil })
```

### Update

Got a question about `has_one` in the comments, so just updating.  The trick here is that `includes()` expects the name of the association but the `where` expects the name of the table.  For a `has_one` the association will generally be expressed in the singular, so that changes, but the `where()` part stays as it is.  So if a `Person` only `has_one :contact` then your statement would be:

```rb
Person.includes(:contact).where(contacts: { person_id: nil })
```

### Original

Better:

```rb
Person.includes(:friends).where(friends: { person_id: nil })
```

For the hmt it's basically the same thing, you rely on the fact that a person with no friends will also have no contacts:

```rb
Person.includes(:contacts).where(contacts: { person_id: nil })
```

Comment: You can incorporate this into a scope which would be much cleaner.

Comment: Far better answer, not sure why is the other one rated as accepted.

Comment: @smathy this does not work for a has_one association.

Comment: Yes it does, just that assuming you have a singular name for your `has_one` association you need to change the name of the association in the `includes` call.  So assuming it was `has_one :contact` inside `Person` then your code would be `Person.includes(:contact).where( :contacts => { :person_id => nil } )`

Comment: I just found that you cannot use this approach along with ``pluck``, which requires ``joins`` instead of ``includes``. But joining will not retrieve the proper records. Any idea?

Comment: Using `pluck` works fine for me.  Ie. just adding to the end of the code above does the right thing for a field in `Person`

Comment: How would you make this work for the reverse side of the association? Starting with the model where the `belongs_to` association lives, i.e. find a friend with no person.

Comment: `Friend.where :person => nil`

Comment: Sorry, brain fade.  The answer for the case of the through table is the same as from person to friend: `Friend.includes(:contacts).where( :contacts => { :friend_id => nil })`

Comment: Actually, the truth is that the last field in the join table doesn't need to be related to the model being searched for, it just has to be a field in that table - so actually you can just use `id`, so the last one becomes: `Friend.includes(:contacts).where( :contacts => { :id => nil })` and then to switch that to return `Person` just change the `Friend` to `Person`

Comment: Can someone explain me how to adapt this in a scope? Right now i have `scope :without_company, -> { includes(:company).where( :companies => { :user_id => nil } }` and is returning me **syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ')'**

Comment: Because you have an open paren after your `where` that you never close

Comment: What about if you want to add a condition? E.g. People without any friends named Sam? (including anyone without any friends).

Comment: @CHawk I bet that if you guess at how to solve that, you'll be right.

Comment: If you're using a custom table name in your Friend model ( `self.table_name = "custom_friends_table_name"`), then use `Person.includes(:friends).where(:custom_friends_table_name => {:id => nil})` .

Comment: Any idea how to get this working if the `has_one` or `has_many` association relies on class inheritance and STI?  e.g. with this example `Person.includes(:contacts).where( :contacts => { :id => nil } )` would fail if the table for contacts was using an STI table name that's different from its model name (e.g. like `entities` if the rails model contact.rb was: `contact < entity`)

Comment: Right, so as with the custom table name example in the comment before yours, you need to use the table name in the where clause, eg. `...where( entities: { id: nil } )`

Comment: Could you update with [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57116483/8122487)? I know OP asked for solution without SQL here, but I think it's worth having one with optimal query on db server.

Comment: @smathy A nice update in Rails 6.1 adds a `missing` method to do exactly [this](https://blog.saeloun.com/2020/01/21/rails-6-1-adds-query-method-missing-to-find-orphan-records)!

Comment: It is, just in the edge docs because 6.1 isn't out yet: https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/WhereChain.html#method-i-missing

Comment: What is the opposite of missing so that i can get the NON orphan records in an associationrelation as well ? I have tried subtracting from Person.all, but i get back an array instead.

Comment: Just `Person.joins(:contacts)`

Comment: I absolutely cannot wait to upgrade to rails 6.1 to use `.missing()`

Comment: Question: What about when you want Persons who are not friends with "user X". It can be done with a subquery, but can i use `missing` for that?

Comment: No, missing only applies to the whole association, but no need for a subquery, you'd just use: `Person.joins(:friends).where.not(friends: { id: user_x.id })`

Answer (score 191):

smathy has a good Rails 3 answer.

**For Rails 5**, you can use `left_outer_joins` to avoid loading the association.

```
Person.left_outer_joins(:contacts).where( contacts: { id: nil } )
```

Check out the [api docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-left_outer_joins). It was introduced in pull request [#12071](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/12071).

Comment: Are there any downsides to this? I checked and it loaded 0.1 ms faster then .includes

Comment: Not loading the association is a downside if you actually access it later, but a benefit if you don't access it. For my sites, a 0.1ms hit is pretty negligible, so `.includes` extra cost in load time wouldn't be something I would worry much about optimizing. Your use case may be different.

Comment: And if you don't yet have Rails 5, you can do this:
`Person.joins('LEFT JOIN contacts ON contacts.person_id = persons.id').where('contacts.id IS NULL')`
It works just fine as a scope as well. I do this all the time in my Rails projects.

Comment: The big advantage to this method is memory savings. When you do an `includes`, all of those AR objects are loaded into memory, which can be a bad things as tables get larger and larger. If you don't need access to the contact record, the `left_outer_joins` does not load the contact into memory. The SQL request speed is the same, but the overall app benefit is much larger.

Comment: This is really good!  Thanks!  Now if the rails gods could perhaps implement it as a simple `Person.where(contacts: nil)` or `Person.with(contact: contact)` if using where encroaches too far into 'properness' - but given that contact: is already being parsed and identified as an association, it seems logical that arel could easily work out what's required...

Comment: if I'm not mistaken, Person.joins() would do the exact same thing as Person.left_outer_joins() as I believe a LEFT JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN will return the same results? I believe it's just sematics. I don't think you need to use the word "outer" anywhere in the code as it's redundant for this type of join. The important thing is to use `.joins()` instead of `.includes()` -- [have a look here](https://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/difference-between-a-left-join-and-a-left-outer-join/)

Comment: If you like to get only those Persons what has Contacts then do `Person.left_outer_joins(:contacts).where.not( contacts: { id: nil } ).distinct`

Comment: @FireDragon you're misstaken. `.joins` creates an INNER JOIN (which is the default for almost every db i know of). Thats why `.left_outer_joins` was introduced in the first place.

Comment: @max that's right I meant to say that `.left_joins` is an alias for `.left_outer_joins` - both of these create the same LEFT OUTER JOINS sql

Answer (score 14):

Persons that have no friends

```
Person.includes(:friends).where("friends.person_id IS NULL")
```

Or that have at least one friend

```
Person.includes(:friends).where("friends.person_id IS NOT NULL")
```

You can do this with Arel by setting up scopes on `Friend`

```
class Friend
  belongs_to :person

  scope :to_somebody, ->{ where arel_table[:person_id].not_eq(nil) }
  scope :to_nobody,   ->{ where arel_table[:person_id].eq(nil) }
end
```

And then, Persons who have at least one friend:

```
Person.includes(:friends).merge(Friend.to_somebody)
```

The friendless:

```
Person.includes(:friends).merge(Friend.to_nobody)
```

Comment: I think you can also do: Person.includes(:friends).where(friends: {person: nil})

Comment: Note: The merge strategy can sometimes yield a warning like ```DEPRECATION WARNING: It looks like you are eager loading table(s)``` ```Currently, Active Record recognizes the table in the string, and knows to JOIN the comments table to the query, rather than loading comments in a separate query. However, doing this without writing a full-blown SQL parser is inherently flawed. Since we don't want to write an SQL parser, we are removing this functionality. From now on, you must explicitly tell Active Record when you are referencing a table from a string```

Answer (score 12):

Both the answers from dmarkow and Unixmonkey get me what I need - Thank You!

I tried both out in my real app and got timings for them - Here are the two scopes:

```
class Person
  has_many :contacts
  has_many :friends, :through => :contacts, :uniq => true
  scope :without_friends_v1, -> { where("(select count(*) from contacts where person_id=people.id) = 0") }
  scope :without_friends_v2, -> { where("id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(person_id) FROM contacts)") }
end
```

Ran this with a real app - small table with ~700 'Person' records - average of 5 runs

Unixmonkey's approach (`:without_friends_v1`)   813ms / query

dmarkow's approach (`:without_friends_v2`) 891ms / query (~ 10% slower)

But then it occurred to me that I don't need the call to `DISTINCT()...` I'm looking for `Person` records with NO `Contacts` - so they just need to be `NOT IN` the list of contact `person_ids`. So I tried this scope:

```
  scope :without_friends_v3, -> { where("id NOT IN (SELECT person_id FROM contacts)") }
```

That gets the same result but with an average of 425 ms/call - nearly half the time...

Now you might need the `DISTINCT` in other similar queries - but for my case this seems to work fine.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, you're probably looking at a solution involving SQL, but you could set it in a scope and then just use that scope:

```
class Person
  has_many :contacts
  has_many :friends, :through => :contacts, :uniq => true
  scope :without_friends, where("(select count(*) from contacts where person_id=people.id) = 0")
end
```

Then to get them, you can just do `Person.without_friends`, and you can also chain this with other Arel methods: `Person.without_friends.order("name").limit(10)`

Answer (score 1):

A NOT EXISTS correlated subquery ought to be fast, particularly as the row count and ratio of child to parent records increases.

```
scope :without_friends, where("NOT EXISTS (SELECT null FROM contacts where contacts.person_id = people.id)")
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, to filter out by one friend for instance:

```
Friend.where.not(id: other_friend.friends.pluck(:id))
```

Comment: This will result in 2 queries rather than a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using a subquery:

```rb
# Scenario #1 - person <-> friend
people = Person.where.not(id: Friend.select(:person_id))

# Scenario #2 - person <-> contact <-> friend
people = Person.where.not(id: Contact.select(:person_id))
```

The above expressions should generate the following SQL:

```sql
-- Scenario #1 - person <-> friend
SELECT people.*
FROM people 
WHERE people.id NOT IN (
  SELECT friends.person_id
  FROM friends
)

-- Scenario #2 - person <-> contact <-> friend
SELECT people.*
FROM people 
WHERE people.id NOT IN (
  SELECT contacts.person_id
  FROM contacts
)
```