# Finding Unassociated Records in Rails 3 with Mongoid?

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319400/want-to-find-records-with-no-associated-records-in-rails-3), except I'm trying to do this in Mongoid.

I have two models:

```
class ImageUpload
  include Mongoid::Document

  referenced_in :post
end

class Post 
  include Mongoid::Document

  references_many :image_uploads
end
```

How can I select the image uploads that are not associated with any post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried following:

```
ImageUpload.where(:post_id => nil)
```

Comment: So obvious but I didn't even think of it. Thanks.

Comment: be sure to add :dependent => :nullify otherwise your images will still have a post_id even after the post is deleted