# Active Record: How to select records that have zero has_many relations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-many

I'm using Rails 3, and I have the following:

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :releases
  # more code
end

class Release < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :artist
  # more codez
end
```

If I want to select all artists that have NO releases, how would I do this without hardcoding SQL?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319400/want-to-find-records-with-no-associated-records-in-rails-3