# Rails find record with zero has_many records associated

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many

This seems fairly simple but I can't get it to turn up on Google.

If I have:

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
end
```

I want to find all cities that have no photos. I'd love to be able to call something like...

```
City.where( photos.empty? )
```

...but that doesn't exist. So, how do you do this kind of query?

---

**Update:**
Having now found an answer to the original question, I'm curious, how do you construct the inverse?

IE: if I wanted to create these as scopes:

```
scope :without_photos, includes(:photos).where( :photos => {:city_id=>nil} )
scope :with_photos, ???
```

Comment: Since I discovered this question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/5319400/417872) I guess this can be closed. It's probably worthwhile to have one more way to find this in google though, this kind of thing is hard to describe and therefore hard to search for.

Comment: In Rails 4, you can use the new `.not` method for the inverse. `City.includes(:photos).where.not( photos: {city_id: nil} )`

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Bah, found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5570221/417872

```
City.includes(:photos).where(photos: { city_id: nil })
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19080147/492465 - also answers your question about constructing the inverse and does all this with Arel

Comment: I don't understand how this is correct? Isn't it looking for photos that don't have a `city_id`? That's not the same as cities for which there is no photo with that particular city's id as the foreign key.

Comment: @sixty4bit - It works because when you do `includes` it does a join. In a SQL join, you get all the fields of both tables (in this case cities and photos) for each row unless you change the projection of the query. So, he's using that to his advantage to check whether a required database identifier is present. If it's not, then there was no record on the photos side of the join. You could also use `photos: {id: nil}` if that is more clear.

Comment: If you’re using Rails 6.1 or higher, use where.missing to find missing relationship records.

E.g.`City.where.missing(:photos)`

Answer (score 62):

In **Rails versions >= 5**, to find all cities that have no photos, you can use [`left_outer_joins`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#left-outer-joins):

```
City.left_outer_joins(:photos).where(photos: {id: nil})
```

which will result in SQL like:

```
SELECT cities.*
FROM cities LEFT OUTER JOIN photos ON photos.city_id = city.id
WHERE photos.id IS NULL
```

Using [`includes`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations):

```
City.includes(:photos).where(photos: {id: nil})
```

will have the same result, but will result in much uglier SQL like:

```
SELECT cities.id AS t0_r0, cities.attr1 AS t0_r1, cities.attr2 AS t0_r2, cities.created_at AS t0_r3, cities.updated_at AS t0_r4, photos.id AS t1_r0, photos.city_id AS t1_r1, photos.attr1 AS t1_r2, photos.attr2 AS t1_r3, photos.created_at AS t1_r4, photos.updated_at AS t1_r5
FROM cities LEFT OUTER JOIN photos ON photos.city_id = cities.id
WHERE photos.id IS NULL
```

Comment: What's the Rails 4 version of this?

Comment: @fatuhoku  In **Rails 4** you can either use [Yossi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23756239/6231376) (for cleaner SQL) or use `includes` (for less brittle code). In Rails 5 `left_outer_joins` is the way.

Answer (score 24):

When trying to find records with no matching records from the joined table, you need to use a LEFT OUTER JOIN

```
scope :with_photos, joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN photos ON cities.id = photos.city_id').group('cities.id').having('count(photos.id) > 0')
scope :without_photos, joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN photos ON cities.id = photos.city_id').group('cities.id').having('count(photos.id) = 0')
```

Comment: this is much slower compared the Andrew answer, but it works

Comment: Actually I would say this is less complicated - this answer demonstrates the actual technique used, or the actual DB query that will be needed. The accepted answer essentially obfuscates this.

Comment: If anyone else is wondering, `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is equivalent to `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 8):

I used a join to get all the ones *with* photos:

`scope :with_photos, -> { joins(:photos).distinct }`

Easier to write and understand, for that particular case. I'm not sure what the efficiency is of doing a join vs doing an includes, though

Comment: adding to this way of doing it, to get all records that _don't_ have an association: `City.where.not(id: City.joins(:photos).distinct)`

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the accepted answer gives you exactly what you're looking for, as you want to do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and that answer will give you a `INNER JOIN`.  At least in Rails 5 you can use:

```
scope :without_photos, left_joins(:photos).where( photos: {id: nil} )
```

or you can use `merge` in cases where namespacing will make the `where` clause cumbersome:

```
scope :without_photos, left_joins(:photos).merge( Photos.where(id: nil) )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not running Rails 5+ and performance is a must-have, avoid useless ActiveRecord creation and get just what you need:

```
City.where("NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM photos WHERE photos.city_id = cities.id LIMIT 1)")
```