# Select all records that are not associated with other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two tables `pages` and `menu_items`, `pages` HAS MANY `menu_items` and `menu_items` belongs_to `pages`. In Rail 4 how can I select only those `pages` that are not linked with `menu_items`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Woah sorry, forgot about this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the following should work:

```
Page.includes(:menu_items).where( menu_items: { page_id: nil} )
```

or

```
Page.find(:all, conditions: { :menu_items.count: 0 } )
```

or

```
Page.where('id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(page_id) FROM menu_items)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `Page.where` is what you're looking for. Effectively the `where` method calls a search through the `Page` database for all objects of the specified type. By calling it with the parameter of the menu's id equal to nil, you are searching for all pages where there is no menu id.

Ideally you would like to call `Page.where(page.menu_items.empty?)`, however, of course, this isn't allowed.

Looking around [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613717/rails-find-record-with-zero-has-many-records-associated) is more or less exactly the same as yours. They solve it with:

```
Page.includes(:menu_items).where( :menu_items => {:page_id=>nil} )
```

Comment: There is no `menu_items_id` column in `pages` table.