# Hide record in Rails model if nested_attributes are empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model, nested-attributes

I have two models in my Rails app: `Listing` and `ListingPhoto`. I want to set some kind of scope on my model that removes `Listing`s that have no nested `ListingPhoto`s. These are being pulled in from an external API, so I have no easy way to control these saving.

`Listing` looks like this:

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base

  acts_as_taggable_on :listing_types

  has_many :listing_photos
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :listing_photos, allow_destroy: true

  private

end
```

`ListingPhoto` looks like this:

```
class ListingPhoto < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :listing
  validates :listing, presence: true
  mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader
end
```

What would I need to add to my `Listing` model to stop listings with empty photo sets showing up?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613717/rails-find-record-with-zero-has-many-records-associated on how to add `with_photo` scope. Then in your controller use `Listing.with_photo` in place of `Listing.all` when preparing a list of listings to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add static method in Listing model:

```
def self.with_photos
    includes(:listing_photos).where.not(:listing_photos => {:listing_id => nil})
end
```

and then just easily call:

```
Listing.with_photos
```