# Rails 4 ActiveRecord query for empty association on self referential has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Here's the setup:

```
# app/models/booking.rb

class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Associations
  belongs_to :parent_booking, class_name: "Booking"
  has_many :child_bookings, class_name: "Booking", foreign_key: "parent_booking_id"
end
```

This is not a required relationship, so not all Bookings have a parent_booking or child_bookings.

Trying to create a query which returns an ActiveRecord::Relation of all Bookings which do NOT have any child_bookings, regardless of whether parent_booking is present or not.

The following example (based on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613717/rails-find-record-with-zero-has-many-records-associated)) works for scenarios where the relationship is between different models. However, it does not work with the self referential relationship due to the fact that the records are in the same table. Instead, it returns an ActiveRecord::Relation of all Bookings which do not have a parent_booking.

```
Booking.includes(:child_bookings).where(bookings: { parent_booking_id: nil })
```

The following returns the correct objects, but is extremely inefficient as it has to query the database for every record. Also, it returns it as an array instead of an ActiveRecord::Relation (more concerned with the inefficiency).

```
Booking.select { |b| b.child_bookings.empty? }
```

I'm quite possibly overlooking a simple solution, but extensive searching hasn't turned up anything yet. Thanks!

Comment: I think this should work : `Booking.where({ parent_booking_id: nil })`

Comment: @MuhammadYawarAli That returns Bookings that have no **parent**; I need to return Bookings that have no **children**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd add a [counter cache](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) and then query `Booking.where(child_booking_count: 0)`

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. Marked as solution as it solved both the efficiency issue AND returned as ActiveRecord::Relation. This will also help other areas querying the size of the association. Good stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I think the inefficiency comes from the eager loading. If you just do a standard left join I think you'll find performance to be fine:

`Booking.joins("LEFT JOIN bookings child_bookings ON child_bookings.parent_booking_id = bookings.id").where(child_bookings: {id: nil})`

I know you lose the ability to use the AR association, but ActiveRecord has not yet decided to include left joins. If you want them, I've made a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/ozydingo/70de96ad57ab69003446) that you could use to add it and the additional method `:without` that was made with this type of thing in mind: then you could write `Booking.without(:child_bookings)`

Comment: Makes sense. Another answer kept the ability to use the AR association so I went with that, however I'll probably use this in other scenarios where the AR association isn't important. Thanks!

Comment: Sure! The counter cache is a good solution and will be even quicker than this after it's set up since it only has to query one table without any joins.

Answer (score 1):

One way to query 0 child records is :

```
parent_ids = Booking.parent_booking_ids
Booking.where('id NOT IN (?)',parent_ids)
```

Hopefully it will return the required records.