# Rails/SQL: Find parents that have no child or have all children with a condition

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I need to find parents that either have no child OR have all children exclusively with condition (status = 1).

```
class Parent
  has_many :children
end

class Child
  enum status: [ :confirmed, :not_confirmed ]
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

I know the first part, which is finding parents with no children.

```
Parent.joins(:children).where('count(children) = 0')
```

Rails answer.

Comment: Do you want a Rails answer, or a SQL answer?

Comment: @jarlh Rails answer if possible

Comment: You might want to see [Rails find record with zero has_many records associated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39410256/6231376)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're using Postgres, you can use a `NOT EXISTS` query:

```rb
# Parents with no children
Parent.where.not('exists (?)', Child.where('children.parent_id = parents.id').select(1))
```

This query performs better than anything requiring a join, as an `EXPLAIN` will show you that Postgres will accomplish this with a `Nested Loop Anti Join` operation.

Comment: what does select(1) do in the above code?

Comment: It's just a placeholder value. The meat of the sub-query is the WHERE condition, so it's testing whether `SELECT 'i_dont_care_value' WHERE important_condition = is_true_or_not` produces any rows at all.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution in Rails:

```
grp = Parent.left_outer_joins(:children).distinct
models = grp.where('children.id IS NULL').or(grp.where('children.status = 1'))
```

Basically you need to use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (see `left_outer_joins` in [Rails5 Reference](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#left-outer-joins)).

I do not think your example of the first part works.  It would return an error message like

```
# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  
# aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE
```

and also Rails `joins` is `INNER JOIN`.