# Rails User.joins.not(...) in Active Record?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Im looking to query all Users without Comments in a single sql query?

Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

So I want the opposite of this:

```
User.joins(:comments).group('users.id')
```

But not like this: (because it generates two queries)

```
User.where.not(id: Comment.pluck(:user_id))
```

Maybe something like this?

```
User.joins.not(:comments).group('users.id')
```

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Try `User.includes(:comments).where(comments: { id: nil })`

Comment: @MrYoshiji This is bang on and more correct than the accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: NOTE: In Rails 6.1, you can just use `User.where.missing( :comments )`. See https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/WhereChain.html#method-i-missing and this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5570221/293280.

Comment: While the solution proposed by @MrYoshiji might work (if includes is handled internally using eager_load), it's not guaranteed to work. In case AR executes a preload, there will be no join happening and the query will fail.
If you need a join to occur, use joins (or on a modern rails left_outer_joins).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can accomplish this with:

```
User.includes(:comments).where.not(comments: { id: nil })
```

This will result in raw SQL that looks something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `users`.`*` FROM `users` LEFT OUTER JOIN `comments` ON `comments`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` WHERE `comments`.`id` IS NULL
```

For accomplishing this via a subquery, see the below answer.

**Old Answer**:

You can do something like

```
User.where.not(id: Comment.select(:user_id))
```

If you wanted a single (though nested) query.

Otherwise, check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables for using an outer join.

Comment: Will it use subquery or 2 different queries?

Comment: @thethanghn in this case it will result in a sub query. Any time you pass an `ActiveRecord::Relation` (which is what the active record query methods like `select` and `where` return) to a query method, a sub query will result.

Comment: Why are you using the `not` in `User.includes(:comments).where.not(comments: { id: nil })`? This seems wrong to me. You want the condition to be where `id IS NULL`, not the inverse of that.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `postgresql` you can do something like this

```
User.joins("LEFT join comments c on users.id = c.comment_id").
select("users.id").
group("users.id").
having("count(users.id) = 1")
```

This will generate this query

```
select u.id from users u
LEFT join comments c 
on c.comment_id = u.id
group by u.id
having count(u.id) = 1
```

This query is not generating two SQL (neither nested sql), the above answer does.

Comment: What does `c` and `u ` in that query stand for ?

Comment: @thiebo "c" is an alias for the comments table & "u" is an alias for the users table. You can find more about SQL aliases [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(SQL))

Comment: I used this successfully, except I changed the having clause to test for the absence of the child record. Something like `.having("count(comment.id) = 0")`

Answer (score 3):

Starting in Rails 6.1, you can use

```rb
User.where.missing(:comments)
```

https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/WhereChain.html#method-i-missing

Answer (score 2):

Another simple solution
`User.where("id NOT IN (?)", Comment.pluck(:user_id))`

Comment: Good for quick ad hoc queries in rails console, especially when there is no model relationship between tables. BUT...this is not a good route for production code.

Comment: Just to add to David Hempy, the reason why it is not good for production code is because it requires **two** queries to run: one to get the `user_id`s of all the `Comment` records and then two to get all the `User` records not in those `user_id`s. It's possible and better to do this in a single query.