# How to look if User has posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I defined a `User` Model and a `Message` Model:

with **User**:

```
has many: messages
```

and **Message**:

```
belongs_to: user
```

I know how to get the users Messages:

```
 @users = User.all
 @users.messages
```

But how can i get all `Users` that have Messages and all Users that dont have Messages? Thanks

Comment: Have a look here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html.  There are examples on that page for doing this kind of data retrieval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.includes` method:

```
users_without_messages = User.includes(:messages).where(messages: { id: nil })

users_with_messages = User.includes(:messages).where('messages.id IS NOT NULL')
```

Answer (score 1):

A SQL-ish answer:

> But how can i get all Users that have Messages

```
User.where('id IN (SELECT DISTINCT(user_id) FROM messages)')
```

> and all Users that dont have Messages? Thanks

```
User.where('id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(user_id) FROM messages)')
```

Comment: also, look here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319400/want-to-find-records-with-no-associated-records-in-rails-3) for a better answer using joins.