# default_scope doesnt work with association models's scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, default-scope

I have a model setup like the following:

```
class Subject
  has_one :background_job, as: :backgroundable_job
  has_many :sub_subjects

  default_scope { includes(:background_job).where( background_jobs: { backgroundable_job_id: nil } ) } 
end
```

The default_scope returns the subjects that don't have a background_job

Here is the SubSubject model:

```
class SubSubject
  belongs_to :subject

  scope :ordered, -> { joins { subject }.order('subjects.order_number') }
end
```

But when I do subject.sub_subjects.ordered I get the following error:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "background_jobs"
LINE 1: ...ubjects"."id" = "sub_subjects"."subject_id" AND "backgroun...
```

When I call subject.subjects (without the ordered) it just works fine

I also tried setting a default_scope with a Subject's own attribute, and it works fine as well

I can't figure it out what's wrong, please help

EDIT:

The SQL query that rails performs when I do SubSubject.joins{subject}.order('subjects.order_number') is:

```
SELECT "sub_subjects".* FROM "sub_subjects" INNER JOIN "subjects" ON "subjects"."id" = "sub_subjects"."subject_id" AND (background_jobs.backgroundable_job_id IS NULL) ORDER BY subjects.order_number
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319400/want-to-find-records-with-no-associated-records-in-rails-3) question, I had to write the SQL almost manually and use a little bit different approach:

```
default_scope { where('subjects.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(
                      backgroundable_job_id) FROM background_jobs)') }
```