# Rails sql search through has_one relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This query in notices_controller.rb:

```
Notice.includes(:active_comment_relationship).where(active_comment_relationship: {id: nil} ).limit(50)
```

is producing this error:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "active_comment_relationship"
```

I can't see what's wrong with the code. I've looked at answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319400/want-to-find-records-with-no-associated-records-in-rails-3) and as far as I can tell it should be working.

notice.rb:

```
has_one :active_comment_relationship, class_name: "Commentrelationship",
                                      foreign_key: "commenter_id",
                                      dependent: :destroy
has_one :supernotice, through: :active_comment_relationship, source: :commentee
```

Answer (score 1):

In the includes part you need the association name, but in the where clause you need the table name, which usually is the pluralized name. In this case I assume it is something like:

```
Notice.includes(:active_comment_relationship).where(commentrelationships: {id: nil} ).limit(50)
```

Answer (score 0):

The table name has to be plural, `:active_comment_relationships`:

```
    Notice.includes(:active_comment_relationships).where(active_comment_relationships: {id: nil} ).limit(50)
```

Comment: It's a has_one relationship, so it has to be `.includes(:active_comment_relationship)`. 
Also, changing `.where(active_comment_relationship: {id: nil})` to `.where(active_comment_relationships: {id: nil})` makes no difference, it still produces the same error.

Comment: @Bazley, just try `.includes(:active_comment_relationships)`. It has to be like this because the name of the table is `active_comment_relationships`. It does not depend on which type of relationship you use

Comment: @Bazley, seems like it has to be `.includes(:commentrelationships)`, because this is the actual name of the table. It does not depend on the type of relationship You use, it's just SQL `INNER JOIN` that needs a name of a table, not a relationship

Comment: @Bazley, I was wrong, first part has to be as it is. try using `.where(commentrelationships: {id: nil} )` or `.where('commentrelationships.id IS NULL')` in the second part

Comment: Thank you Ivan, you are right. The following code is correct:
`Notice.includes(:active_comment_relationship).where(commentrelationships: {id: nil} ).limit(50)`
Do you want to write the official answer or shall I?