# Rails4: How to display the data when association data doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

What I'd like to do is to display the data as followings;

- Display `a.title` if `a.title` exists but `@school.rooms.where(day: d).first.name` doesn't exist
- Display `@school.rooms.where(day: d).first.name` if `a.title` doesn't exist but `@school.rooms.where(day: d).first.name` exists

It works if both data exist.
Although I tried some code such as `exist?`, `nil?` and so on, I couldn't.

It would be appreciated if you could give me the best way in Rails.

View code

```
<div class="row">
  <h1 class="col-md-12"><%= @school.title %></h1>
</div>
<div class="row">

  <% @school.days.each do |d| %>

    <h3>Day<%= d %></h3>

    <% @school.articles.where(day: d).each do |a| %>
      <strong><%= a.title %></strong></p>
    <% end %>

    <p>Room: <%= @school.rooms.where(day: d).first.name %></p>

  <% end %>

</div>
```

Controller code

```
class SchoolsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @school = School.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Model code

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :articles
    has_many :rooms

    def days
      self.articles.pluck(:day).uniq
    end
end


class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :school
end


class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :school
end
```

Schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150999999999) do

  create_table "rooms", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "school_id"
    t.integer  "day"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "detail"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "articles", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "school_id"
    t.integer  "day"
    t.string   "start_time"
    t.string   "end_time"
    t.integer  "category"
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "contents"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "schools", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

It would be appreciated if you could give me any suggestion.

Comment: I like the second answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319400/want-to-find-records-with-no-associated-records-in-rails-3).

Answer (score 0):

If you will always have **either** piece of data present (IE `a.title` exists if `@school.rooms.where(day: d).first.name` does not), you can use the following:

```
<p>Room: <%= a.title || @school.rooms.where(day: d).first.name %></p>
```

If **neither** exist, you should be able to use a "default" value:

```
<p>Room: <%= a.title || @school.rooms.where(day: d).first.name || "default" %></p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Rich Peck.
Is it possible to use`a.title` after end of each?
Although I tried, NameError 'undefined local variable or method "a"' was displayed.

Comment: No, the last entry is meant to be the "default" - when all the rest have failed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Rich Peck. Although I tried the last entry `<p>Room: <%= a.title || @school.rooms.where(day: d).first.name || "default" %></p>`,the following error message was displayed. `undefined local variable or method "a" for #<#<Class:0x5270cb8>:0x3b05d10>`