# Find all record without association with a certain field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord

My question is very similar to this question: [Want to find records with no associated records in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319400/want-to-find-records-with-no-associated-records-in-rails-3)

But with a twist. Let's use their example and add my problem:

```
class Person
   has_many :friends
end

class Friend
   belongs_to :person
   attr_accessor :type # this can be 'best' or 'acquaintance'
end
```

I want to get all people without 'best' friends. The normal query for most cases that I see is to get people without any friends. And that would be:

```
Person.includes(:friends).where( :friends => { :person_id => nil } )
```

But that's not what I want. Is there a way to get all people who have no 'best' friends regardless of how many other type of friends they have?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using rails 4.2 which supports negation on queries you could do something like:

```
Person.includes(:friends).where.not( friends: { type: "best" } )
```

In any other case:

```
Person.includes(:friends).where("friends.type != 'best'")
```

**Update**

Maybe a little bit off-topic, but you may consider using [enum](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) from active record so you can map these kind of things, like:

```
class Friend
   belongs_to :person
   enum type: {best: 0, acquaintance: 1}
end
```

Then you could query like this:

```
Person.includes(:friends).where.not( friends: { type: Friend.types[:best] } )
```

Which makes it more readable, ruby-friendly and avoids using strings since the value is stored as an integer in the db.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward, though not the only nor necessarily the most performant, way to do this is with a `NOT EXISTS` subquery:

```
Person.where('NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM friends WHERE person_id=persons.id AND type=?)', 'best')
```

You can define this as a scope on `Person` for easy composition.

Note: I also want to point out that, while Gustavo's solution reads like you expect, it will return anyone who has a friend who's not their best friend (not just people without ANY best friends). This is due to how SQL's where clauses function on a per-row basis, and have trouble asserting over groups or one-to-many relations.