# How to tell a model has an empty relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

There maybe an answer for this but I might not be searching with the correct words. How to tell my model has an association object? Makes sense?

```
#Foo Model:
 has_one :bar

#User Model:
 has_many :foos

User.first.foos.bar #=> {object}
```

Basically what I want is, give me all of `foos` that has no `bar`. Is this possible?

Instead of adding a table onto `foo`: `has_bar: <boolean>`, then:

```
User.first.foos.where(has_bar: false)
```

Edit:

This maybe a [duplicate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319400/want-to-find-records-with-no-associated-records-in-rails-3) based on Albin's answer. But it still works for Rails 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the answers in this question you will find multiple ways of doing it: [Want to find records with no associated records in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319400/want-to-find-records-with-no-associated-records-in-rails-3)

The way I would do it is:

```
User.first.foos.includes(:bar).where(bars: { foo_id: nil } )
```

Comment: Thanks but I have the `has_one`: `User.first.foos.includes(:bar).where(bars: {foo_id: nil})`. I have upvoted for the link but you have a tiny typo. Update and I'll answer. Maybe a duplicate post?

Comment: I cant seem to edit you answer. Please to change to my suggestion in comments. Your answer still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

```
User.first.foos.select { |foo| foo.include(:bar) && foo.bar.id.nil? }
```

Comment: There isnt an association id on `Foo`. Albin has pointed me to the correct post/answer. Have a look.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I didn't wake up yet (:
I updated it with another possible alternative, thanks! @Sylar