# Query empty polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to find all `Foo`'s that don't have a `Bar` associated with them. I know this doesn't work but something along the lines of `Foo.where(barable: nil)`.

**Foo model**

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :bars, as: :barable
end
```

**Bar model**

```
class Bar < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :barable, polymorphic: true
end
```

**Tables**

```
Foo(id: integer, name: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)

Bar(id: integer, barable_type: string, barable_id: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

Comment: Hi ferne97, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40511534/8759209), that should help

Comment: Your example doesn't reflect a true polymorphic use case, which hides the complexity here. You also need a `Baz` that is `barable`, which exposes the issue - you can't just query the join table id is null as you would for a normal has-many/belongs-to relationship because you don't know the join table name without asking the Rails class.

Answer (score 0):

```
Foo.joins('LEFT JOIN bars ON bars.foo_id = foos.id').where('bars.id is null')
```

Comment: `left_outer_joins` doesn't seem to work with polymorphic associations

Comment: True, I've changed to another way. This should work with polymorphic associations. @ferne97

Comment: There is no `foo_id` on `bars` in his example. If there were, it'd be a has-many/belongs-to relationship, rather than a polymorphic one with `barable_id` and `barable_type` on `Bar` and nothing on any other model.