# Rails scope according to an attribute of it's child (or having no childeren)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have 2 models: `Sophead` and `SopheadIssue`.

`SopheadIssue belongs to Sophead`,

`Sophead has many SopheadIssues` (optional).

I want to create a scope on the Sophead model for Sopheads that match EITHER of the 2 conditions:

1. The Sophead has no SopheadIssues at all
2. The Sophead has no SopheadIssues with a SopheadIssue attribute of (active=true).

At the moment I have tried the following:

```
scope :no_issue, -> { joins(:sophead_issues).where.not("active = ?", true) }
```

But this isn't working as it is missing Sopheads without any SopheadIssues.

Any help much appreciated.
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `joins` is `INNER JOIN` and it filters out the `sophead` without `sophead_issues`. You need to use [left_joins](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-left_joins) here:

```
scope :no_issue, -> { left_joins(:sophead_issues).where("sophead_issues.active != ? OR sophead_issues.sophead_id IS NULL", true) }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following should work, though I'm unable to test and confirm this at the moment:

```
scope :active, -> { joins(:sophead_issues).where.not(sophead_issues: { active: true }) }

scope :no_associations, -> { joins(:sophead_issues).where.not(sophead_issues: { sophead_id: nil }) }

scope :no_issue, -> { active.no_associations }) }
```

I've broken this down into a couple of queries for my own sanity, though were I able to test, I imagine you should be able to combine them using `or` and `not`. However, I'm not certain how to implement this without testing it out a little.

Basically, the `active` scope is self explanatory: you find the `sophead_issues` with `active` set to `true`.

The `no_associations` your `sopheads` without an association. More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319400/want-to-find-records-with-no-associated-records-in-rails-3#answer-5570221) if you're interested.

Finally, `no_issue` combines the two methods, returning your collection.

You could refactor this into a class method, or two class methods that chain to form the scope, depending on your preference.

Edit: or use @IgorDrozdov's approach, that's much cleaner :) (Unless you're < Rails 5, where `left_joins` was introduced.)