# Rails Conditional Where ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation Returns an Empty Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get a collection conditionally:

```rb
# app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
if ...
  @articles = current_user.articles.where(tags: [])
else
  @articles = current_user.articles.where(tags: params[:id])
end

# app/models/article.rb
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :taxonomies
  has_many :tags, through: :taxonomies
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :link, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id }
end
```

The `else` conditional of `where(tags: params[:id])` works fine. But I'm not sure how to get the collection when the articles have no tags.

Here is an example of two articles in my database. One has a tag, one does not and returns `#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>`

```
> Article.first.tags
  Article Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" ORDER BY "articles"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Tag Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taxonomies" ON "tags"."id" = "taxonomies"."tag_id" WHERE "taxonomies"."article_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["article_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Tag id: 1, name: "inbox", permalink: "inbox", user_id: 1, created_at: "2020-12-31 18:55:41", updated_at: "2020-12-31 18:55:41">]>

> Article.last.tags
  Article Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" ORDER BY "articles"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Tag Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taxonomies" ON "tags"."id" = "taxonomies"."tag_id" WHERE "taxonomies"."article_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["article_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

Assigning `where(tags: nil)` or `where(tags: '')` return the same empty array:

```
> current_user.articles.where(tags: nil)
  Article Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."user_id" = ? AND "articles"."id" IS NULL LIMIT ?  [["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []>

> current_user.articles.where(tags: '')
  Article Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."user_id" = ? AND "articles"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["user_id", 1], ["id", nil], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []>
```

I've tried `current_user.articles.includes(:tags).where(tags: { article_id: nil })` option mentioned in [Want to find records with no associated records in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5570221/3921815), but all that does is return an SQL error `SQLException: no such column: tags.article_id`.

How can I assign articles that have no tags to `@articles`?

**Edit:**

After trying more options from [Want to find records with no associated records in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5570221/3921815), I was able to get this working using:

```rb
current_user.articles.left_outer_joins(:tags).where(tags: { articles: nil })
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Want to find records with no associated records in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319400/want-to-find-records-with-no-associated-records-in-rails). Particularly the second answer, the most upvoted. `current_user.articles.includes(:tags).where(tags: { article_id: nil })`.

Comment: For some odd reason, `current_user.articles.where(tags: x)` is checking for an *Article* with the ID of x. Very puzzling.

Comment: I was finally able to get this to work with `current_user.articles.left_outer_joins(:tags).where(tags: { articles: nil })`

Comment: `current_user.articles.includes(:tags).where(tags: { id: nil })` This should also work in your case. checking with `id` here as you tags are associated with `articles` via `taxonomies`