# Find Non Orphan records in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Following up on the question : [Want to find records with no associated records in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319400/want-to-find-records-with-no-associated-records-in-rails)

I am wondering how I can get all the NON orphan records returned as an AssociationRelation instead of an Array. When trying to subtract the total records of the table from the rails 6 .missing ones, the result is correct, but it's in the form of an array.

Here is a console example :

```
p = ProductResearch.first
(Product.all - p.products.where.missing(:keywords)).class
=> Array
```

How do I get the association ?

( With the help of @max below I found a query, without missing, that returns the expected result as an association. It's like :

```
irb(main):206:0> p.products.includes(:keywords).where.not(keywords: { id: nil }).class
=> Product::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation
```

and it does return the non orphan ones only.

Comment: you mean `all.count - where.missing.count` ?

Comment: But you get back an ActiveRecord Relation instance, not an https://blog.saeloun.com/2020/01/21/rails-6-1-adds-query-method-missing-to-find-orphan-records. This is a good summary on how to do it

Comment: how about `where.not.missing` ?

Comment: What's the code you currently have, and is returning an array? Because from the docs it should return a relation. Trying with Rails 6.1.3.2 and it returns a relation as well.

Comment: Yes @LamPhan, this one.

Comment: @SebastianPalma it is like : Product.all - p.products.where.missing(:keywords). It is returning an Array. p.products is an Product::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy

Comment: @Joel_Blum you do get a relation when you are using missing, but you get an array when you try to get the NON missing ones using sth like Product.all - p.products.where.missing(:keywords).

Comment: `-` is delegated to the `records` method, which is a method defined in `Array`, so, the problem isn't using missing, but the `X - Y` procedure.

Comment: yeap. makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
end
```

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
end
```

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      # Referential integrity is for wusses! YOLO!
      t.belongs_to :post, null: true, foreign_key: false
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```
p1 = Post.create!(title: 'Foo')
3.times { p1.comments.create! }
p2 = Post.create!(title: 'Bar')
3.times { p2.comments.create! }
p2.destroy! # orphans the comments
```

If you do an INNER JOIN on posts you will only get rows with at least one match in the join table:

```
irb(main):014:0> Comment.joins(:post)
  Comment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" INNER JOIN "posts" ON "posts"."id" = "comments"."post_id" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Comment id: 1, post_id: 1, created_at: "2021-05-11 08:59:04", updated_at: "2021-05-11 08:59:04">, #<Comment id: 2, post_id: 1, created_at: "2021-05-11 08:59:04", updated_at: "2021-05-11 08:59:04">, #<Comment id: 3, post_id: 1, created_at: "2021-05-11 08:59:04", updated_at: "2021-05-11 08:59:04">]>
```

This gives you the "non-orphaned" posts.

The opposite is of course an OUTER JOIN:

```
irb(main):016:0> Comment.left_joins(:post).where(posts: { id: nil })
  Comment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" LEFT OUTER JOIN "posts" ON "posts"."id" = "comments"."post_id" WHERE "posts"."id" IS NULL LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Comment id: 4, post_id: 2, created_at: "2021-05-11 08:59:26", updated_at: "2021-05-11 08:59:26">, #<Comment id: 5, post_id: 2, created_at: "2021-05-11 08:59:26", updated_at: "2021-05-11 08:59:26">, #<Comment id: 6, post_id: 2, created_at: "2021-05-11 08:59:26", updated_at: "2021-05-11 08:59:26">]>
```

[Rails 6.1 added the `.missing` query method](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/34727) which is a shortcut for the above query:

```
Comment.where.missing(:post)
```

Comment: thanks a lot @max ! I am finding the missing directive really great, which is why i was wondering if there is a way to do it using missing instead of custom joins.

Comment: No, I don't think you can use `.not.missing`. what's the real problem with just using `.joins(:association_name)`?

Comment: no problem at all, I was just wondering, because it looks slicker. I tried not with missing, wasnt working yeah. I guess i will have to resort to joins.

Comment: `.not.missing` would work if it generated `Comment.left_joins(:post).where.not(posts: { id: nil })` but I don't think it does. I guess you could write your own `not_missing` method - but even if its slicker it would still force devs to lookup the method - whereas most should know what `.joins` does.

Comment: yeah, i actuall just tried the left join like, it's not working indeed returns the whole set. Still having trouble getting the non orphan ones using the first join though, i think it's because it's returning joins from the whole table ? Not sure, been a long while since i messed much with joins :D But p.products.count has 58 elements in my case and p.products.joins(:keywords).count returns 240 elements :/ it should return 20. When using the missing one or the left join i do get back 38.

Comment: As in p.products.left_joins(:keywords).where(keywords: { id: nil }).count.   => 38 I basically want to get the other ones :D

Comment: Thats impossible to debug without an actual example of the models, schema and data.

Comment: yeap understandable, maybe i will create a more detailed question if i still can't solve it. I will probably try to mess with the join a little bit, should be a slight tweak to make i work, it's just been a long while since i've worked on joins and they can be a pain :D

Comment: I actually found a solution i think. Using it like : p.products.includes(:keywords).where.not(keywords: { id: nil }).count returns =>20

Comment: `.includes` just does a LEFT OUTER JOIN like `.left_joins` and also preloads the records. https://scoutapm.com/blog/activerecord-includes-vs-joins-vs-preload-vs-eager_load-when-and-where

Comment: not sure, why it worked, but it did. I basically just used a combination of your answer and the answer of the original question i linked above with the inclusion of the not directive. So far working nicely :D Was trying variants and got lucky lol

Comment: Comment.missing won't work, afaik it's a method on relation. So Comment.where(..).missing(..) is the way to go